# Web Service Return Function Specification Instead of Object?

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, functional-programming

Apologies if this question is a duplicate (or if it has an obvious answer that I'm missing) -->

Is there a practice or pattern that involves a web service returning a function definition to the client, instead of a value or object?

For an extra rough outlining example:

I'm interested in the results of some statistical model. I have a dataset of 100,000 objects of class ClientSideClass.

The statistical model sits on a server, where it has to have constant access to a large database and be re-calibrated/re-estimated frequently.

The statistical model takes some mathematical form, like RESULT = function(ClientSideClass) = A*X + B*Y + anotherFunction(List(Z))

The service in question takes requests that have a ClientSideClass object, performs the calculation using the most recent statistical model, and then returns a result object of class ModelResultClass.

In pseudo OOP (again, sorry for the gnarly example) :

My program as a client :

```
static void main() {
   /* assume that this assignment is meaningful and that all
       the objects in allTheThings have the same identifying kerjigger */
   SomeIdentifier id = new SomeIdentifier("kerjigger");
   ClientSideClass[100000] allTheThings = GrabThoseThings(id);

   for (ClientSideClass c : allTheThings) {
      ModelResult mr = Service.ServerSideMethod(c);
      // more interesting things
   }
}
```

With my client side class :

```
ClientSideClass {
   SomeIdentifier ID {}
   int A {}
   double[] B {}
   HashTable<String,SomeSimpleClass> SomeHash {}
}
```

On the server, my main service :

```
Service {
   HashTable<SomeIdentifier,ModelClass> currentModels {}

   ModelClass GetCurrentModel(SomeIdentifier id) {
       return currentModels.get(id);
   }

   ModelResultClass ServerSideMethod(ClientSideClass clientObject) {
       ModelClass mc = GetCurrentModel(clientObject.ID);
       return mc.Calculate(clientObject);
   }
}

ModelClass {
   FormulaClass ModelFormula {}

   ModelResultClass Calculate(ClientSideClass clientObject) {
       // apply formula to client object in whatever way
       ModelResult mr = ModelFormula.Execute(clientObject);
       return mr;
   }
}


FormulaClass {
    /* no idea what this would look like, just assume
         that it is mutable and can change when the model
         is updated */
   ModelResultClass Execute(clientObject) {
    /* do whatever operations on the client object
        to get the forecast result 
        !!! this method is mutable, it could change in
        functional form and/or parameter values */
    return someResult;
   }
}
```

This form results in a lot of network chatter, and it seems like it could make parallel processing problematic because there's a potential bottleneck in the number of requests the server can process simultaneously and/or how blocking those calls might be.

In a contrasting form, instead of returning a result object, could the service return a function specification? I'm thinking along the lines of a Lisp macro or an F# quotation or something. Those could be sent back to the client as simple text and then processed client-side, right?

So the ModelClass would instead look something like this? -->

```
ModelClass {
   FormulaClass ModelFormula {}
   String FunctionSpecification {
       /* some algorithm to transform the current model form
           to a recognizable text-formatted form */
      string myFuncForm = FeelTheFunc();
      return myFuncForm;
   }
}
```

And the ServerSideMethod might look like this -->

```
String ServerSideMethod(SomeIdentifier id) {
   ModelClass mc = GetCurrentModel(id);
   return mc.FunctionSpecification;
}
```

As a client, I guess I would call the new service like this -->

```
static void main() {
   /* assume that this assignment is meaningful and that all
       the objects in allTheThings have the same identifier */
   SomeIdentifier id = new SomeIdentifier("kerjigger");
   ClientSideClass[100000] allTheThings = GrabThoseThings(id);

   string functionSpec = Service.ServerSideMethod(id);
   for (ClientSideClass c : allTheThings) {
       ModelResult mr = SomeExecutionFramework.Execute(functionSpec, c);
   }
}
```

This seems like an improvement in terms of cutting the network bottleneck, but it should also be readily modified so that it could be sped up by simply throwing threads at it.

Is this approach reasonable? Are there existing resources or frameworks that do this sort of thing or does anyone have experience with it? Specifically, I'm very interested in a use-case where an "interpretable" function can be utilized in a large web service that's written in an OO language (i.e. Java or C#).

I would be interested in specific implementation suggestions (e.g. use Clojure with a Java service or F# with a C#/WCF service) but I'd also be stoked on any general advice or insight.